# Isotopy: Definition

Tags: manifolds, definition, geometric-topology

An [isotopy](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Isotopy.html) is a homotopy from one embedding of a manifold $M$ in $N$ to another such that at every time, it is an embedding.

In this definition, I am wondering why $M$ and $N$ are required to be manifolds. What if we replace "manifold" by "topological space" in the definition? How would this modified definition work?

Comment: It works fine for any two topological spaces.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy#Isotopy.